# How to create Custom Formatter in Behat 3

Tags: behat, formatter

Since there is considerable changes in Behat 3 from the earlier versions, When I tried to create a custom formatter in the old way it threw me error. Can anyone post an example about it ?

Comment: You should add what have you tried and the error you get. Please take a look at behat documentation and behat issues from github like: https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/563 , https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/742 and others.Please ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with same question today and here what I've done:

1. Create own extension (check how other extensions are implemented)
2. Extension must implement `\Behat\Testwork\ServiceContainer\Extension`
3. Create `CustomFormatter`, it should implement `\Behat\Testwork\Output\Formatter`
4. Create service definition for your formatter and tag it with `output.formatter`